# sales_flat_order_grid VS sales_flat_order?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, orders

In magento we are updating orders in two tables each time, 
what is the real significance to use two tables,

what is the difference between `sales_flat_order_grid` and `sales_flat_order` tables ,

why we need to store order details in two tables.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`sales_flat_order_grid` works like an index to make displaying, sorting and filtering in the order grid faster and not blocking the real order tables. The source of truth for the shop is `sales_flat_order`.

The grid table is generated from it (see: [Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Abstract::updateGridRecords()](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/d48bebc211cc216aaf78bdf25d7f0b0143d6333b/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Abstract.php#L155-L181).

Comment: is sales_flat_order_grid table has magento model

Comment: @manokarthickkarthick No, only a collection class `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Grid_Collection`, the items are regular order models

Comment: then how can i update the  sales_flat_order_grid  ?

Comment: is collection model allow to update the table?

Comment: Update with updateGridRecords(), see link above

Comment: yes, you can use that method to update a single field for a single entity: `updateOnRelatedRecordChanged('status', $entityId)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52447/discussion-between-manokarthick-karthick-and-fabian-schmengler).

Comment: I guess it's worth noting that adding custom columns to the order grid of the admin panel can negate the benefits of separate tables. Often I see `sales_flat_order*` tables being joined with `sales_flat_order_grid`. Even well-known extensions will do this.

Comment: Good catch @RickBuczynski. The right way, of course, is to add custom columns to the grid table as well.

Comment: Which table can be used for reporting? can I use the grid table?

Answer (score 2):

**sales_flat_order_grid** table is for the Admin Order grid. In grid magento is showing `billing name` and `shipping name`, here shipping name and billing name are stored in another table.

To achieve this we have to join many tables, So they are using two different table.

**sales_flat_order_grid** is for Admin sales grid

And another one(**sales_flat_order**) is to store order details