# Order status out of sync between sales_flat_order and sales_flat_order_grid

Tags: magento-1.9

I've a handful of orders (3 out of about 16,000) where the order status shown in the `sales_flat_order` table differs`from that in the`sales_flat_order_grid table`.

The three orders have the processing status in the `sales_flat_order_grid` table, but `closed`, `on hold` and `complete` in the `sales_flat_order` table.

I'd like to tidy this up. Is there an automatic method which will push the true state of the order contained in `sales_flat_order` into `sales_flat_order_grid`. Failing that is it safe, sensible to modify the database directly, adjusting the status of these orders in the `sales_flat_order_grid` table?

Comment: I have encountered orders not appearing in the `sales_flat_order_grid` immediately, but later they appear.  Have you tried reindexing all?

Comment: @TimCieplowski Thanks for the suggestion, but these orders have been kicking around for over a year now and there have been plenty of more recent orders since. Also I can't see an index for orders, so how would I try and reindex it?

Comment: The command line gives you access to some reindex processes that are not available in the admin.  From the Magento root, you can see a list of them by running `php shell/indexer.php info` and run them all with `php shell/indexer.php reindexall`.

Comment: @TimCieplowski I tried it on an older development copy and it appeared to do the trick. Thank you! I'll report back how well it works in production. Anything I should know about the indexer - is it safe?

Comment: I have responded by adding my comment as an answer, let me know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 2):

I found this [solution by Igor Furseev at Atwix](https://www.atwix.com/magento/refresh-orders-grid-table/), The full code is:

```
<?php
/**
 * @author Atwix Team
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2016 Atwix (https://www.atwix.com/)
 * @package Atwix_Shell
 */
require_once 'abstract.php';

class Atwix_Shell_Free_Order_Grid_Update extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{
    public function run()
    {
        try {
            Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getResource()->updateGridRecords(
                Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')->getAllIds()
            );
            echo 'Done!' . PHP_EOL;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}

$shell = new Atwix_Shell_Free_Order_Grid_Update();
$shell->run();
```

which you save to a file in the shell directory of your Magento installation and then execute with php from the command line with `php shell/orders_grid_update.php`.

I've taken a bit of time to analyse this code, to try and reassure myself that I'm not just implementing a random solution from the internet, which may or may not be right.

The above code gets a Magento collection object for all orders in the system, uses it to generate a list of all the entity IDs (not the same as order ids), which it then passes to `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Abstract::updateGridRecords`.

The `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Abstract::updateGridRecords` method is the method Magento uses itself to update the grid records any time a `sales/order` object is saved. The save method is defined higher up the models hierarchy in `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::save`, where the method generates a call to `Mage_Sales_Model_Abstract::afterComitCallback`, which in turn calls the `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Abstract::updateGridRecords` method.

Looking at `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Abstract::updateGridRecords`, we can see that it builds an insert select query, which will insert (or update) data in `sales_flat_order_grid` based on data from from a select query which joins together `sales_flat_order` and `sales_flat_order_address` (actually joins twice onto `sales_flat_order_address` to get both billing and shipping addresses associated with the order).

I tried the above on a copy of a store and then diffed the databases before and afterwards. The only tables which had changed was `sales_flat_order_grid` as I'd expected. It had modified this table to sort out the orders which were in an inconsistent state.

The only other change the database diff reveated were some double spaces between the firstname and surname on both the billing and shipping addresses. I tracked this down to a code change in `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order::_initVirtualGridColumns` sometime between version 1.6 and 1.9. The earlier version just concatenated a customers first and surname, but the later version concatenated a customers first, middle and surname but mistakenly appeneded a space to both first and middle names during the concatenation, even if the middle name was not present, hence the double space.

I'm not to concerned if the above code messes up the  `sales_flat_order_grid` table as [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/156398/34327) says that the grid table is just for presentation to the admin, and is not the source of truth about an order.

Answer (score 1):

Try reindexing all.

The command line gives you access to some reindex processes that are not available in the admin. From the Magento root, you can see a list of them by running `php shell/indexer.php info` and run them all with `php shell/indexer.php reindexall`.

There is no problem with running `reindexall` in production, but if you have not done it before, make sure you take a DB backup first.  Running in production is generally considered safe, unless you have an underlying issue.  An example to check for in you development DB, after reindexing is that all of your URL rewrites still work properly.

Comment: Hi Tim. I tried this recently and unfortunately it didn't work. I've looked at the source code for `shell/indexer.php` and don't think this could work as there is not an index in the `index_process` table which would cause `sales_flat_order_grid` to be rebuilt.